# Sausage roll pastry - how do I achieve a smooth shiny effect?

Tags: baking, dough, pastry

I came across this on the net and would love to be able to make them for a party next week.

[image: sausage rolls]

http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/296105_10150312607032555_324958872554_8041834_494890086_n.jpg
I've seen pastry like this on sausage rolls in France but don't know how to get the effect.
Is it just puff pastry they use with egg yolk? How is this effect achieved?

Comment: I wonder what those _are_?  Sea creatures of some kind?  They seem suitably alarmed at their impending death-by-being-eaten.

Comment: Those are *darling*!

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not puff pastry at all. It is a rich yeast dough, similar to the dough for an unsweetened brioche. The dough has a low hydration (around 50% or maybe 55%), so it can be rolled out into a sheet, similar to a pizza base, without being sticky. In Europe, these are made with AP flour, not bread flour, they are supposed to be soft and not chewy. If you are looking for a recipe, search for brioche recipes with a low amount of sugar which are intended for kneading by hand instead of a mixer.

From the rolled dough, you have to cut a stripe, maybe 1 cm wide. You also need molds for baking. They look like a long cone, maybe 8-10 cm in height and 2-3 cm in base diameter. (You can roll your own from tin halfcircles, if you have the tools to cut a tin sheet into halfcircles). You wind the strip of dough around the cone and bake it with the cone still inside. Afterwards, you have to remove the cone with care, and so you have the hole where you can put the sausage.

I haven't made or seen the variation with eyes. Obviously, you have to add the pips before baking. I am not sure how the white/dark blob is achieved. It looks like something was piped on before baking, maybe normal and colored eggwhite "snow".

The shiny effect of the crust of this picture seems to be due to baking with steam in a commercial oven. You can't replicate it at home, if you want them to be shiny, you may consider using a glaze or wash.

Comment: You can get some steam with boiling water poured into the oven onto a preheated pan. Not as much as a commercial oven but enough to make things shiny. I agree that a simple egg wash would be the logical way to do this.

Comment: To make a stuffed cone, you use a slightly tappered former (roll up some plastic from a milk bottle), and wrap it with a tappered strip of dough. Either cut it from a slab, or roll it out like playdough, about 50 to 60cm long. Go from just over 1cm down to nothing over it's length